# Gunicorn Keeps Restarting/Breaking on Flask App

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, gunicorn

I have a Flask App I'm trying to transition to running through gunicorn. I'm experiencing a lot of problems with this. Here's the run code for my app:

```
app.run(host=HOST, port=PORT, debug=DEBUG_FLAG)
```

First, if DEBUG_FLAG == true, the app will never actually start up, but will just keep restarting, and hitting it locally won't work. It just does this over and over:

```
gunicorn analytics_service:app                                                                                                                         
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
```

If I start it with DEBUG_FLAG==False, it will actually start up and serve some requests, but will still break and restart frequently for unknown reasons:

```
gunicorn analytics_service:app                                                                                                                         (env: BigQueryTest)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2014 08:59:05] "GET /metrics/ctr?location=blah&start_date=2014-05-21&end_date=2014-06-01 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2014 08:59:15] "GET /metrics/ctr?location=blah&start_date=2014-05-21&end_date=2014-06-05 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 64693)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/Eli/.virtualenvs/BigQueryTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 200, in handle
    rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/Eli/.virtualenvs/BigQueryTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 231, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 447, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
  File "/Users/Eli/.virtualenvs/BigQueryTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 154, in handle_abort
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
----------------------------------------
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

As mentioned, everything works fine if I run through Flask's native server. Issues only arise with gunicorn. Help?

Comment: Is there gunicorn configuration/commandline? Compare to this: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/wsgi-standalone/

Comment: No special configuration. Just starting with `gunicorn analytics_service:app`. All configuration is through Flask right now, an all that does is set host, port, and debug_flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that you are calling `app.run()`.

The `app.run()` function starts Flask's development web server. When you use a web server other than Flask's you do not have to call this function, your web server (gunicorn in this case) will have its own way to start.

Normally the `app.run()` line is inside a `if __name__ == '__main__':` conditional (see the Flask official documentation for an example), so that it only runs when you execute the script directly, as in `python run.py`. I recommend that you add this to your run.py script and retest. If there are any remaining problems please describe.

Comment: Is there documentation on how flask and gunicorn are supposed to interact? I cannot get it to work by guessing, I've got a simple run.py at project root which imports projectname/index.py and calls its `run` method, this method creates Flask app and calls `app.run()`, without this trick imports wouldn't work as intended because "projectname" module wouldn't be found from project root which other files depend on.

Comment: There is nothing special about Flask with regards to gunicorn. It is just a WSGI app, so you can follow the gunicorn docs and use the Flask application instance as your WSGI app.

Comment: Ahaa, I was looking at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/wsgi-standalone/ but http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html was a lot more useful in finding the right syntax and set-up.

Comment: Dude, you are my hero! Thanks a bunch!!! :D